# office 365 bulk add shared mailbox members via powershell

Tags: powershell, office365

I have already created the shared mailbox in o365. 
Now I need to bulk import members to these shared mailboxes.

How to do it in powershell ? 
I want to do something like this

```
$users = import-csv -Path "C:\path\members.csv" -Delimiter ";"
Foreach ($user in $users){
    Add-mailboxpermission -identity "name of the shared mail box" -user $user -accessrights FullAccess
}
```

any thoughts ?

Comment: Please show some of your (sanitizes) csv content. Do you have headers?

Answer (score 0):

Connecting to Office365 would be a good first step:

```
$AdminUsername = "admin@your-domain.onmicrosoft.com" 
$AdminPassword = "YourPassword"
$AdminSecurePassword = ConvertTo-SecureString -String "$AdminPassword" -AsPlainText -Force
$AdminCredential = New-Object -TypeName System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -ArgumentList $AdminUsername,$AdminSecurePassword

$ExchangeSession = New-PSSession -ConfigurationName Microsoft.Exchange -ConnectionUri "https://outlook.office365.com/powershell-liveid/" -Credential $Admincredential -Authentication "Basic" -AllowRedirection
Import-PSSession $ExchangeSession
```

After you have a session you can play with the functions and add some logic:

```
$access = "FullAccess"
$mailbox = Get-Mailbox -Identity YourMailbox
$identity = $mailbox.UserPrincipalName
$permissions = Get-MailboxPermission -identity $identity

$users = Import-Csv -Path "C:\path\members.csv" -Delimiter ";" 
foreach($user in $users){
    try{
        $setPermissions = Add-MailboxPermission -Identity $identity -User $user -AccessRights $access
        Write-Host "Successfully added permissions for $user" -ForegroundColor Green
    }catch{
        Write-Host "Failed to add permissions for $user" -ForegroundColor Red
    }
}
```

Remember to add users based on UserPrincipalName

Comment: Does the problem still exist? Is the script I provided not working? Let me know if I can help you out.